# Where should I place "only" in context?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

A grammar book says I should place adverb between subject and main verb. So this should be right.

> When I was a student, I **only** pulled an all-nighter once.

How about this one?

> When I was a student, I pulled an all-nighter **only** once.

Is it right? Is it idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and idiomatic, and have the same meaning.
The first expression is more common.